# Android HttpUrlConnection: Post Multipart

Tags: android, performance, spring, httpurlconnection, android-networking

I'm trying to post a test File to a spring rest servlet deployed on tomcat using Android. I'm developing on Android 4.1.2, but I have verified same problem on 4.0.3.

The problem is that the file upload requires a very long time (about 70 seconds for a 4MB file), also in local network. The time is equiparable using a 3g connection. I've excluded that it could be a server problem: executing the same call with curl it takes 1 / 2 seconds, and using apache as backend results are the same.

**Using `HttpClient` works fine.**

I'm using Spring Android RestClient 1.0.1.RELEASE and, given Android version and the fact that I'm not overriding default behaviour, it uses HttpUrlConnection instead of HttpClient to make http requests.

I have also implemented my custom ClientHttpRequestFactory in order to manipulate some details of SSL connection and I have defined my own implementation of ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in order to modify authentication header.

I have also set `setBufferRequestBody(false)` in order to avoid `OutOfMemoryException` on big files. But this property have no effects on time required.

**MyClientHttpRequestFactory**:

```
public class MyClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory{

    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection,  String httpMethod) throws IOException {
        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(240 * 1000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(240 * 1000);


        if ("post".equals(httpMethod.toLowerCase())) {
            setBufferRequestBody(false);
        }else {
            setBufferRequestBody(true);
        }
    }

@Override
protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(URL url, Proxy proxy) throws IOException {
    final HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = super.openConnection(url, proxy);

    if (url.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")
        &&
        settings.selfSignedCert().get())
    {
        try {
            ((HttpsURLConnection)httpUrlConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLSocketFactory());
            ((HttpsURLConnection)httpUrlConnection).setHostnameVerifier(new NullHostnameVerifier());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            MyLog.e(LOG_TAG, "OpenConnection", e);
        } 
    } 

    return httpUrlConnection;
}
```

**MyClientHttpRequestInterceptor**:

```
public class MyClientHttpRequestInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        final HttpHeaders headers = request.getHeaders();

        headers.setAuthorization(new HttpBasicAuthentication( settings.username().get(), settings.password().get()));

        if (settings.enable_gzip().get()) {
            headers.setAcceptEncoding(ContentCodingType.GZIP);
        }

        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}
```

And here my Rest call:

```
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = Arrays.asList((ClientHttpRequestInterceptor)myClientHttpRequestInterceptor);

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);

MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
parts.add("file", new FileSystemResource("/sdcard/test/4MB_file"));

HttpEntity<MultiValueMap> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap>(parts);
restTemplate.exchange(myUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Integer.class).getBody();

}
```

Looking at Spring Android source code, the next lines of code my request is passing through are:

```
public ClientHttpRequest createRequest(URI uri, HttpMethod httpMethod) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection connection = openConnection(uri.toURL(), this.proxy);
    prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod.name());
    if (this.bufferRequestBody) {
        return new SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest(connection);
    } else {
        return new SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest(connection, this.chunkSize);
    }
}
```

Because of `this.bufferRequestBody` is `false`, `return new SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest(connection, this.chunkSize);` is executed (with chunkSize = 0)

```
SimpleStreamingClientHttpRequest(HttpURLConnection connection, int chunkSize) {
    this.connection = connection;
    this.chunkSize = chunkSize;

    // Bugs with reusing connections in Android versions older than Froyo (2.2)
    if (olderThanFroyo) {
        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    }
}
```

and then:

```
ClientHttpRequest delegate = requestFactory.createRequest(request.getURI(), request.getMethod());

delegate.getHeaders().putAll(request.getHeaders());

if (body.length > 0) {
    FileCopyUtils.copy(body, delegate.getBody());
}
return delegate.execute();
```

From here is all android subsystem I think..

I have dumped tcp traffic and analyzed it:

```
POST /urlWherePost HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=nKwsP85ZyyzSDuAqozCTuZOSxwF1jLAtd0FECUPF
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; sdk Build/MASTER)
Host: 192.168.168.225:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 4096225

--nKwsP85ZyyzSDuAqozCTuZOSxwF1jLAtd0FECUPF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="4MB_file"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 4096000
```

I've tryed to re-create similar request with curl:

```
curl --verbose 
    -H "Connection: Keep-Alive" 
    -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" 
    -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" 
    -H "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"4MB_file\"" 
    -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" 
    --user xxx:xxx 
    -X POST 
    --form file=@4MB_file 
    http://192.168.168.225:8080/urlWherePost
```

but with curl the post is ok.

Posting json data is not a problem (maybe small body size). But when I try to send "big" files the time increase.

Looking in DDMS shell, on Network Statistics I've also found that the network throughput is never over 250kb in TX. There seems to be a bootleneck, but how to investigate it? Where I can look, which parameter can I change?

Thank you for any suggestion!

Comment: Would you like to try a multipart library, I have written or is using Spring required?

Comment: @fabian At this time I would avoid to replace Spring. But give me more details on such multipart library please!

Comment: Can you give me a mail address or something? I'll send you the code and some instructions for usage

Comment: irc: irc.abjects.net room: #spring_android

Comment: do you really need to add all the messageconverters to the resttemplate?? the less the faster .... ?

Comment: @kamokaze71 Thank you for this response! I have also tryed in registering only FormHttpMessageConverter but I see no differences.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the MultipartEntity method? I had the same problem when downloading big amounts of JSON data from the server, but I switched to this method and caught all the data that the server provided me.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://myurl.com");

try {
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

    entity.addPart("type", new StringBody("json"));
    entity.addPart("data", new JSONObject(data));
    httppost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
} catch (JSONException e){
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I have problem with HttpUrlConnection, not with HttpClient. As stated in my question, HttpClient works! Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To upload big files, You can use this  library [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

Answer (score 0):

For simple and easy to use, I recommend this lib https://github.com/koush/ion.
I use it on my project and it works perfectly.